# Which factors contribute to your Champion Grade?

Tags: league-of-legends

As the new Champion Mastery is put into live servers, you now get a grade on how well you did after your game, and that affects how many Champion Mastery Points you get.

What are some of the key factors in calculating your grade, such as CS, KDA, and other statistics, and how important are they in getting a S+ (Perfect Grade)?

Comment: One thing I know for good is that a game won grants better points than a game lost albeit got good KDA in that champion.

Comment: @Randomizer Yes, but that doesn't affect your champion grade.

Comment: Although this question is very interesting, I'm voting to close it since Riot has explicitly stated that they aren't going to reveal the specific factors that contribute to the champion grade because the system could be abused. [Interview](http://www.surrenderat20.net/2015/03/red-post-collection-champion-mastery-q.html#2)

Comment: @Jutschge Ah, I'll vote to close as well then.